# subclassing from multiple class library in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, subclassing, xlpagertabstrip

I have a ViewController that want to inherit from 2 libraries,

for example:

```
class ViewController : BaseViewController, ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController{
}
```

I know swift won't let me do that, So what is the best way to inherit from both clasess.

Comment: Multi-level inheritance!

Comment: if you using https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip there no need of inheritance

Comment: @IOSSingh then how do you do it without inheritance?

Comment: I sense a [XY-Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should explain what you want to achieve, not how.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I did explain what i want to achieve, and IOS Singh said there's no need inheritance, and I am asking how? his answer is basically an example from github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip which I know already and doesn't explain my question.

Comment: You are explaining that you want to use a certain tool (inheritance from 2 super classes). Instead you should explain what you want to achieve by using this — non-existing — tool. With your current question (*what is the best way to inherit from both classes*) the only valid answer can be: You can't.

Comment: I have this exact same issue.  I am using a "Base" view controller for all  sections of my app.  For one specific section I require a tabview.  My app already requires me to subclass my base viewcontroller, but I also need to subclass UITabbedViewController for this small section.  I don't want to subclass tabbedviewcontroller for the entire application so I am looking to find a way to subclass both for this small section or somehow rework my app to be able to use all the classes in my Base viewcontroller and still be able to subclass an alternate XXXXViewController class if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple Class Inheritance is not supported on Swift, simply You can achieve via **multi-level inheritance**, in your case

1. Subclass **BaseViewController** from **ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController** on base class Declaration

   `class BaseViewController : ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {
         //Body
          }`
2. And then further Subclass your **ViewController** from **BaseViewController**

   `class ViewController : BaseViewController {
     //Body
       }`

Comment: Indeed , But as per need we can achieve, And i think If we are trying to do Multiple Inheritance on Swift then we have to work on Protocols So that some common things can be solved, But on basis of the question here , we are trying to provide both functionality from two libraries (or simply classes ) (i suppose ). So Multilevel inheritance is only option here .

Comment: One doubt here. Consider a scenario:

Comment: One doubt here. Consider a scenario:

What if my "LoginViewController" inherits from "BaseViewController" and I don't want any methods of "ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController" in my new  "LoginViewController", then what we need to do. Problem here with me was "ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController" forced me to implements its datasource, which in my case was not needed.

What I did is created a new file called "BaseNewViewController" and copied all the code of "BaseViewController".

Am I right?

Comment: Humm, That might be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do Multi-level inheritance!

```
class BaseViewController : ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController{

}

class ViewController : BaseViewController {

}
```

Comment: I think it makes sense if I am making my own two simple classes. But I don't think it will be easy to multiple inherit from two external libraries. I hope there's simpler answer.

Comment: You can do it with your classes!